# How to clear cache of other applications in android M (6.0) programmatically

Tags: java, android, caching

Hi I am trying to clear cache of installed applications, I have achieved this below android 6.0 versions.But When While I am trying to achieve it in android 6.0, it throws java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user nor current process has android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE. But I have defined it in mainfest.xml. But I also read it can't be done in android 6.0 due to security reasons, but the most popular applications like Clean Master clears cache. how do clean master clear application's cache? Please help me. I have stuck here. Thanx.

Comment: Hi guys, I got the hack that is used by other apps to clear cache memory in android M (6.0). Now I am able to clear cache memory in android M. Thanks for replying guys.. Thanks again

Comment: @jitendar Sign can you share what was the solutions.

Comment: @sector11 they uses accessibility service to do it...

Comment: @JitendraSingh Can you please answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56206710/clearing-the-cache-on-os-versions-above-marshmallow question. I have started a bounty worth 100 points.

Comment: Did anyone get any solution?